# How do I call an Ant macro from inside another macrodef?

Tags: ant, macrodef

I have a build.xml, from here I call a macro:

```
<import file="macro_file.xml" />
<ant-macro message="Hello, World!" />
```

and my macro_file.xml file looks like this:

```
<macrodef name="ant-macro">
    <attributes name="message"/>
    <sequential>
        <echo message="@{message}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

How can I call another macro inside the `ant-macro` macro?

I tried in the below manner, but its gives an error.

```
<macrodef name="ant-macro">
    <attributes name="message"/>
    <second-macro messge="hi"/>
    <sequential>
        <echo message="@{message}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

The `second-macro` macro is also defined in the macro_file.xml file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macro executes everything inside its `sequential` element. Just put your second-macro call inside it:

```
<macrodef name="ant-macro">
    <attributes name="message"/>
    <sequential>
        <second-macro message="hi"/>
        <echo message="@{message}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```